# Why were my questions based on Thomas Kinkade unilaterally deleted or closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

[Where can vistas per Thomas Kinkade's 'High Country Christmas', be found in Canada?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/94987/13759) is closed allegedly for being 'too broad'.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/94985/13759, https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/94986/13759, https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/94984/13759,
https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/94988/13759 were all suspended after 5 votes, but then unilaterally deleted.

I am sorry if posting them consecutively is the problem, but they all concern different vistas that I genuinely wish to see in reality.

Comment: Given your username and stated intent in your profile, I would suggest you should expect substantially increased scrutiny for anything that appears remotely spammy.  Posting 4 copies of basically the same question, none of which are very good questions per this site's FAQ, looks at least somewhat spammy.

Answer (score 9):

Let's say I am asking that I want to see a vista like this in the picture.

[image]
*World of Avatar in Nighttime by Jedi94, CC BY-SA 4.0*

Why it is a bad question? Several reasons:

1. We want to have an *answerable* question. Both in this picture or in the paintings of Thomas Kinkade it is unclear if such a place exists. Thomas Kinkade does not draw something he saw in real life, he essentially invented all the scenes for maximal emotional impact. In fact both Avatar and Thomas Kinkade have the very same goal: Draw something which should create some longing.
2. We want to have a question for which we can have some measure that the answer actually answers the question. What criterion could we use that some place *does fulfill* the vista ? For actual photographs it is pretty clear: The location where the photo was taken.

But what do we need for (in order Avatar / Thomas Kinkade):

- a dark blue / an orange tint sky?
- glowing organisms / wood houses built like in the Kinkade picture?
- Blue illuminated big trees and ferns / a curvy stone bridge over a small river?

Not only we do not have an idea that a place like this exist, we do not know what property of the vista would fulfill your criteria. We cannot answer the question earnestly.

3. Even if a picture was realistic enough that some place may exist, you are asking for Canada which is the *fourth-largest country on Earth*. Much, **much** too broad, the criteon for travel is if the amount of possible answers is above something like a dozen, it moves into the *too broad* section.
4. Bad strategy from your side. You posted consecutively several questions without making sure that the question is on-topic. One off-topic question is no big deal, but if you review a question and you have invested time for looking up the question, giving explanations for being off-topic and then finding exactly the very same question again and again is aggravating. It gives the impression that you do not care if your question is on topic.

Comment: Of course, there's now an "Pandora/Avatar" world area opening in Walt Disney World in Florida which has many of these characteristics.

Comment: @mkennedy It doesn't just have many of those characteristics... it has exactly those characteristics. The picture in this answer is actually a real photograph of the Pandora area in Disney's Animal Kingdom in Florida at night.